# Collapsing toolbar - toolbar under statusbar

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I've recently bumped to problem with coordinator layout. When I try to create simple collapsing toolbar layout as in [this](http://antonioleiva.com/collapsing-toolbar-layout/) example, toolbar apears to be under status bar as in screenshot below (on preLolipop devices everything works fine, because app don't draw under under statusbar).

[image: toolbar under statusbar (see back arrow)]

Code snippet of my Activity layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageCalculationDetail"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_dummy_calculation"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/transparent"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <include layout="@layout/container"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

My Styles (only v21) where BaseAppTheme parent is Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="BaseAppTheme">
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:colorButtonNormal">@color/button_state_list</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/transparent</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: Post your styles.xml file.

Comment: I've added style into question

Comment: What about your manifest file? Have you specified correct style there? Post that one too. Because I tried the same layout and everything in fine on lollipop emulator.

Comment: What is the value `@color/transparent`? Change it to `#00000000`, if it's not.

Comment: Value of transparent is @android:color/transparent, which is #00000000

Answer (score 7):

Well I figure it out, problem was that I had

```
<item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>
```

in my toolbarStyle of BaseAppTheme (for other actvities, everything works well, for collapsing toolbar with translucent status bar not). After setting

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
```

to my toolbar, everything works fine.

Answer (score 2):

For me

Adding an Attribute fitSystemWindows="false" to Toolbar in XML worked.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
```

By putting this in your styles you're telling Android that your app is responsible for drawing the stuff behind the system bar.  That's why the "dirty hack" in the other answer is technically correct if this flag is set.

Unless you have an explicit reason for the flag to be true (I suspect not), set it to false so that the OS properly offsets your content for you.  Your status bar should still be translucent.

Comment: No setting this value to false doesn't make any difference

Answer (score 0):

Try by removing `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` from ImageView..

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageCalculationDetail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_dummy_calculation"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>
```

Comment: After removing this flag, toolbar is under status bar, but statusbar stops being transparent and whole collapsing toolbar is disorted, this is not desired effect

Comment: will you please post screenshot ?

Answer (score 0):

Programmatically, you can change this behavior by clearing and adding relevant flags via Android's `Window` class methods. Write a custom function in the Activity concerned and pass it the color resource ID of your choice:

***Kotlin***:

```
fun setStatusBar(color: Int) {
    val window = this.window
    window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS)
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS)
    window.statusBarColor = ContextCompat.getColor(this, color)
}
```

***Java***:

```
public void setStatusBar(int color) {
    Window window = this.getWindow();
    window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
    window.setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, color));
}
```

Then, call the function from your Activity's overridden `onCreate` method right after the `setContentView(R.layout.your_layout)` line. For example:

***Kotlin***:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.your_layout)
    setStatusBar(R.color.colorPrimaryDark)
    ...
}
```

***Java***:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);
    setStatusBar(R.color.colorPrimaryDark);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Apply a breakpoint to include a marginTop to the toolbar for lollipop devices or above.

values/dimens.xml

```
<dimen name="toolbar_margin_top">0dp</dimen>
```

values-v21/dimens.xml

```
<dimen name="toolbar_margin_top">24dp</dimen>
```

an then in your layout:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
  .....
  android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/toolbar_margin_top"
```

Comment: This seems more like a workaround, I woud like to some clean solution, there is no top margin in [example](http://antonioleiva.com/collapsing-toolbar-layout/)

Comment: If you want to have a transparent status bar, it is the only way to fix it. Else, you need to disable android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds property in your styles:  <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">false</item>

Answer (score -1):

NOTING WORKS FOR ME.

For me solution was simple :

add `android:fitsSystemWindows="false"` in ***Top CoordinatorLayout View***